# Can't Pass Int variable through Function in Java that Returns an Int array

Tags: java, arrays

The code I have is as follows:

```
int diceAmount = sInput.nextInt();
int[] dice = dice.rollDice(diceAmount);
```

The Dice.java class is here:

```
    public static int[] rollDice(int diceAmount) {
       int[] dice = new int[diceAmount];
       for(int i=0;i < diceAmount;i++){
          dice[i] = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
       }
       return dice;
    }
```

The error that I get is that:
"Cannot invoke rollDice(int) on the array type int[]".

It should work considering all I am doing is passing an integer variable through and setting the returning array to my own dice variable.

It works if I don't set the dice.rollDice(diceAmount); equal to anything but that's not what I want.

Thank you.

Comment: s/dice.rollDice/Dice.rollDice/

Comment: You are trying to invoke a method on array not on object then how could you ask java to call a rollDice method to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] dice = Dice.rollDice(diceAmount);
             ^
```

Comment: This worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the name of your object instante of `Dice` is `dice` as well as the integer array. Therefore the compiler deduces that you want to call `rollDice` on the integer array.

```
Dice dice = new Dice();
int diceAmount = sInput.nextInt();
int[] diceArray = dice.rollDice(diceAmount);
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering class Name as Dice so the correct function calling should be

```
int diceAmount = sInput.nextInt();

int[] dice = Dice.rollDice(diceAmount);
```

Please note the problem was

that your object name and array name were both same thats why the compiler was giving you error.

Comment: This also worked, thanks for noticing that.